# JMeter Java Test - ${__UUID()} function in JSON doesn't work

Tags: java, performance, http, jmeter

The task:
I need to perform a post request to an endpoint.
Request body type is JSON:

```
{
   "id": "${__UUID()}"
}
```

I want to simulate 10 users that each will send a payload with unique "id" field generated.

From JMeter GUI it works as expected, but from Java Code it seems not to be recognized and reads it like a simple string or so.

Here is the Java Code:

```
public JMeterClient httpSamplerProxy(String name, String endpoint, String payload, String httpMethod) {
    Arguments arguments = new Arguments();
    HTTPArgument httpArgument = new HTTPArgument();
    httpArgument.setMetaData("=");
    httpArgument.setValue(payload);
    List<Argument> args = new ArrayList<>();
    args.add(httpArgument);
    arguments.setArguments(args);

    HTTPSamplerProxy httpSamplerProxy = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
    httpSamplerProxy.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
    httpSamplerProxy.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
    httpSamplerProxy.setName(name);
    httpSamplerProxy.setEnabled(true);
    httpSamplerProxy.setPostBodyRaw(true);
    httpSamplerProxy.setFollowRedirects(true);
    httpSamplerProxy.setAutoRedirects(false);
    httpSamplerProxy.setUseKeepAlive(true);
    httpSamplerProxy.setDoMultipart(false);
    httpSamplerProxy.setPath(endpoint);
    httpSamplerProxy.setMethod(httpMethod);
    httpSamplerProxy.setArguments(arguments);
    httpSamplerProxies.add(httpSamplerProxy);

    return this;
}
```

where **payload** is a json in a string representative.

I Use JMeter 5.4.1

Besides that I need this to work, how can I enable logging of Post Body in Java to see it in console?

Answer (score 2):

I was missing dependency of functions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding this to class path the function got recognized